# Python : AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dict of int, list. What I'm trying to do is loop through `something' and if the key is present in the dict add the item to the lsit or else create a new list and add the item.
This is my code.

```
levels = {}
if curr_node.dist in levels:
   l = levels[curr_node.dist]
   l.append(curr_node.tree_node.val)...........***
else:
   levels[curr_node.dist] = []
   levels[curr_node.dist].append(curr_node.tree_node.val)
   levels[curr_node.dist] = curr_node.tree_node.val
```

My question is two-fold.
1. I get the following error,
`Line 27: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'`
`Line 27 is the line marked with ***`
What am I missing that's leading to the error.

2. How can I run this algorithm of checking key and adding to a list in a dict more pythonically.

Comment: You assigned an integer here: `levels[curr_node.dist] = curr_node.tree_node.val`. What was that meant to do, you *replaced* the list object there.

Comment: `l` has a value returned from levels dict. If it is a integer. You are trying to append to a integer, which is causing this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set a list first, then *replace that list* with the value:

```
else:
   levels[curr_node.dist] = []
   levels[curr_node.dist].append(curr_node.tree_node.val)
   levels[curr_node.dist] = curr_node.tree_node.val
```

Drop that last line, it breaks your code.

Instead of using `if...else`, you could use the [`dict.setdefault()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) to assign an empty list when the key is missing, and at the same time return the value for the key:

```
levels.setdefault(curr_node.dist, []).append(curr_node.tree_node.val)
```

This one line replaces your 6 `if: ... else ...` lines.

You could also use a [`collections.defaultdict()` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

levels = defaultdict(list)
```

and

```
levels[curr_node.dist].append(curr_node.tree_node.val)
```

For missing keys a list object is automatically added. This has a downside: later code with a bug in it that accidentally uses a non-existing key will get you an empty list, making matters confusing when debugging that error.